# XML, how to retrieve the last item in the list

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML structure:

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>Classic termos 1 liter röd</name>
      <categories>
         <category>Varumärken</category>
         <category>Stelton</category>
         <category>KAMPANJ</category>
         <category>STELTON - MODERNA KLASSIKER</category>
         <category>I köket</category>
         <category>Dukning</category>
         <category>Termosar</category>
      </categories>
      <SKU>920</SKU>
```

To retrieve for example the "name" I do this:

```
$produktnavn = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But how do I retrieve the last "category" item in the list? Here called "Termosar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of elements in a `DOMNodeList` using the **length** property, and use that to grab the last element (minus one, because the elements are zero-indexed):

```
$categories = $dom->getElementsByTagName('category');
echo $categories->item($categories->length - 1)->nodeValue;
// Termosar
```

See https://eval.in/905244